# How can I permanently disable dialogs?

Tags: google-chrome, dialog

Some annoying websites (like Stack Exchange) contain dialogs. [image: SE]

It's annoying.

So how can I permanently disable these dialogs on Chrome?

Comment: It won't work on Chrome.

Comment: @bleh I am not sure what other sites are you referring to but as far as stackexchange is concerned, you can refer to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24186/let-me-turn-off-the-navigate-away-popup) **TLDR** [Why are you often entering text and then backing out?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/24190)

Comment: I know, I just used that as an image example for people who don't know what dialogs are